# ¿Cómo puedo unir dos arrays numpy en una?

Tags: python, python-2.7, numpy, diccionarios

Estoy intentando guardar un diccionario de palabras según un fichero ordenando las palabras segun su tamaño pero me salta un error: KeyError: '\xc7'. No me llega a leer todo el fichero del diccionario

```
def readDic(filename, alfabetASCII):

    dic = dict()

    with open(filename, 'r') as dic_file:
        for palabra in dic_file.readlines():
            p = str(palabra.rstrip())

            if not dic.has_key(str(len(p))):
                dic[str(len(p))] = np.array([[]])

                para = np.array([[]])
                for i in xrange(len(p)):
                    para = np.append(para, [[alfabetASCII[palabra[i]]]], axis=1)

                dic[str(len(p))] = np.append(dic[str(len(p))], para, axis=1)

            else:
                aux = np.array([[]])

                for j in xrange(len(p)):
                    aux = np.append(aux, [[alfabetASCII[palabra[j]]]], axis=1)

                #print aux ##pintem la paraula que volem introduir en el diccionari
                dic[str(len(p))] = np.append(dic[str(len(p))], aux, axis=0)

    print dic
```

---

El problema es que cuando intento leer el archivo hay algún símbolo raro como 'Ç' y no soy capaz de leerlo.

Comment: No necesitas convertir a `str()` las claves del diccionario, puedes directamente usar números (`len(p)`). No obstante esto no guarda relación con el error que mencionas. Ese error parece más bien deberse al acceso a  `alfabetASCII[palabra[i]]`. No sabemos qué contiene `alfabetASCII`, pues es un parámetro que recibe la función, pero se intuye que será algún tipo de diccionario cuyas claves son caracteres ascii. Cuando `palabra[i]` no es ASCII, no encuentra esa clave. Falta contexto para más detalles (por ejemplo la llamada a la función o qué representa ese segundo parámetro).

Comment: alfabetASCII es un diccionario con las letras del alfabeto relacionadas con su valor en ASCII. El actual problema que tengo es que el diccionario que intento leer tiene una letra 'Ç' que no me la lee como tal, lee un simbolo extraño. he intentado añadir ese simbolo a mi alfabetASCII pero no he solucionado el error.

Comment: No necesitas un diccionario para obtener el código ascii de cada letra. Puedes usar `ord(palabra[i])` para ello. En cuanto al carácter "raro" se debe seguramente a que el _encoding_ del fichero no es el que python supuso al abrirlo. Si muestras qué carácter "raro" es el que te sale podríamos tratar de averiguar cuál sería el encoding correcto y convertirlo al leer.